# Vue - есть возможность использовать пробел в этом месте {{ item.start date }}?

Tags: vue.js, vue3, vue-router

Есть такой тестовый массив доступный через API

```
// 20231015201254
// http://localhost:3000/api/users

[
  {
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "dn": "5421",
    "start date": "2011/04/25",
    "salary": "$320,800"
  },
  {
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "dn": "8422",
    "start date": "2011/07/25",
    "salary": "$170,750"
  },
]
```

соответственно вывожу в список, все работает если нет start date (тут пробел)

```
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in users">
            {{ item.name }}
            {{ item.position }}
            {{ item.office }}
            <strong>{{ item.dn }}</strong>
            {{ item.start date }}
            {{ item.salary }}
          </li>
```

Есть ли решение или надо переделывать массив?

Comment: `item['start date']`

Comment: @nörbörnën Точно! Забыл про такое. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно сказали в коментарии, надо делать так

```
item['start date']
```